# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: “null”

Tags: android, exception, calendar

I'm creating Events calendar. I'm this exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: “null”`

[CalendarView.java](http://pastebin.com/86wrn8bD)

**Utility.java**

```
public class Utility {
    public static ArrayList<String> nameOfEvent = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> startDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> endDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                        new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                        null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        // fetching calendars id
        nameOfEvent.clear();
        startDates.clear();
        endDates.clear();
        descriptions.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

            nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
            startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
            endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
            descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
            CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        return nameOfEvent;
    }

    public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(2990): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
 E/AndroidRuntime(2990):    at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
 E/AndroidRuntime(2990):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:342)
 E/AndroidRuntime(2990):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
 E/AndroidRuntime(2990):    at com.examples.android.calendar.Utility.readCalendarEvent(Utility.java:36)
 E/AndroidRuntime(2990):    at com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView$1.run(CalendarView.java:184)
```

Why im getting this? any one help me. Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: Can you upload the code as well ?

Comment: You are parsing a String to a Long, and the string is null.

Comment: It is your `Utility.readCalendarEvent()` that has problem, not `CalendarView`

Comment: @Vigbyor See the code above i have posted..

Comment: @Aprian CalendarView in my class name see in that.. `Utility.readCalendarEvent()`

Comment: your dtstart/dtend value seems to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your following statements are creating error,

```
startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
```

Just change them as following and try again.

```
startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3).trim())));
endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4).trim())));
```

Your field might contain a white space which you need to remove before converting them in to Long Data type.

Comment: Shows error `Cannot invoke trim() on the primitive type long`

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    `startDates.add(getDate(cursor.getLong(3)));
     endDates.add(getDate(cursor.getLong(4)));`

instead of 
    `startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
     endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));`